# Git find similarities (opposite of diff?)

Tags: git, diff

I know I can use

```
git diff branch1..branch2
```

to compare two branches and see the changes.

I'm looking for the opposite - the amount of differences between the two branches is large and I want to understand what has remained the same.

How can I achieve this?

Note: One of the branches has squashed a number of its commits, so they no longer share a recent common parent in the commit tree.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `git difftool`, like this:

```
git difftool --dir-diff branchA branchB
```

And use the appropriate tool.

- On Windows, Winmerge is pretty handy (on Windows) to check for differences.
- On Linux (or Windows) kdiff3 can do the job too.

Comment: This shows me the differences between two branches, the same as `git diff`. In my question I explain that this is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the unified diff format with a huge amount of context so no lines are skipped, and filter out the lines that differ.

```
git diff -U9999 HEAD~1 HEAD | egrep -v '^[+-@]|^diff|^index'
```